# Improving startup time of compiled python program using tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, pyinstaller, tkcalendar

I am creating a GUI program to schedule part inspections in my company. I am using tkinter with tkcalendar to give a dropdown for users to select due dates. Everything works well when I run it inside python, however when I compile it with PyInstaller, the program takes 30-40 seconds to open.

I have found that the majority of this time is taken importing tkcalendar.

I found that tkcalendar is the time consuming module by adding print statements throughout the code and recompiling with PyInstaller so it shows the terminal. I dug deeper into tkcalendar and discovered that Babel is the specific module holding things up. Is there a way of reducing the load time of babel?

I discovered that you need to add the `--hidden-import="babel.numbers` flag to PyInstaller when using tkcalendar. Missing this flag means the exe doesn't work at all.

I have tried both:

`import tkcalendar`

and

`from tkcalendar import DateEntry`

Is there a way of speeding this up? Is there an alternative to tkcalendar that also provides date pickers?

Comment: Actually, you can't do much for speeding up loading modules but importing `tkcalendar` doesn't take long for me about 5 seconds. Maybe you have other modules installed which take your speed.

Comment: As I say, the problem comes when importing tkcalendar. I traced the problem in the calendar to importing babel.

Comment: Have you tried using [virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and build your app inside it?